# Can Model Classes contain Methods, and Constructor

Tags: c#

**Q**: `Can Model Classes contain Methods, and Constructor ?" *[BEST PRACTICE]*

I have an employee Model class which consists of the Employee's name, age, salary etc...

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

so can the above `Model Class` contain some self updating methods *[like updating the employee's age every 1 hour with a timer or something]* and\or constructors or it is better to handle all that things from the executer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A model should contain all logic related to the model (this is DSL) so, yes it can update itself each hour. and when u define auto properties, it's same as defining setters and getter, so of course you can add methods, and constructors as well.

Answer (score 6):

Why couldn't they? The real answer is: it depends on your use case. Patterns, such as something being a *model class*, are recommendations, common ways of doing things, not unbreakable dogmas.

Note: The example “updating the employee's age every 1 hour with a timer or something” is fundamentally wrong. Storing age is fundamentally wrong, unless you are storing a snapshop to some moment in time. A much better solution would be to store date of birth, and compute the age. For example, by defining an `Age` property with a getter only.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put my 2 cents here.

I will start with this: *It can be dangerous*

There is nothing wrong with adding simple CRUD-like methods in your models, but... it thins the layer of separation between your model and your business logic.

I've many times witnessed these methods getting 'enhanced' over time and at some point ending up with logic which does not fit the purpose of a model. The result: hard dependency between your 'model' and your 'controller'.

It's not that it is wrong, but it opens 'portals' which someone can abuse.

If you want to have a more strict architecture, you can consider adding your operations in a 'Manager-like' class:

```
    Car {
       string type;
       int price;
    }

    CarManager {
       public CarManager(Car car) {...}

       public ChangePrice(...) {...}
       public ChangeType(...) {...}
    }
```

... the manager class can now apply validations, exception handling, logging etc, without the concern that it violates your architecture.

Conclusion:

- **Yes**, you can add simple CRUD operations in your model.
- **Concern**: mind their usage.

---

**Edit:**

Missed that there is an ask to "*updating the employee's age every 1 hour with a timer or something*".

In my book this is a no no :). The model's purpose should be limited to data storage only. Periodically updating information is a pure business logic operation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the class is being used.

There is nothing in the language that does not allow it.  But depending on what frameworks you are using and how you are using the classes in your code as to where to put different pieces of functionality.

There is no best answer for every situation.